# Private Cocoapods with SVN repo is not a git repo

Tags: ios, svn, cocoapods

I managed to do a private cocoapods on using git. Now I am trying on SVN. I already set up the specs repo and library at the SVN server. I created my PodSpec for SVN (s.source = { :svn => "svn://username@web.com/iOSLibs/Forms", :tag => s.version.to_s }). Now I am trying to pod install I get the "repo is not a git repo." error. I know since I am referencing an svn repo. What am I missing in the setup?

Btw I was using cocoapods-repo-svn plugin to setup my local repo.

Answer (score 0):

Currently for Specs repo only git repositories are supported, take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1747)

Comment: Specs repo, I have that setup and working. Pod install does not clone with SVN is the problem

Comment: ... because only git repositories are supported by 'pod' utility